# Java memory usage breakdown - native library (DLL) usage

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks

My Java program is taking up huge amounts of memory ~3GB and I have set xmx300MB. Additionally different tools report different memory usage.

**jcmd**: 576MB

**Task Manager**: 967MB

**Resource Monitor**: 3478MB

[image: java memory usage]

When I close the program Task Manager shows the memory usage dropping by about 3GB. My question is how can I see what is using this memory? It seems like it is not java due to the output I see by jcmd. I suspect it might be a DLL that my Java program is using. Are there any tools which can be used here?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [toolset and instructions](https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/troubleshooting-native-memory-leaks-in-java-applications).

You can first confirm your suspicions that it is the DLL by enabling Native Memory Tracking with `-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary` (or `detail`), then re-check with `jcmd VM.native_memory` to verify it's not Java doing native memory allocation.

If you don't see a large obvious chunk under the `Native Memory Tracking` part, you'll be out of Java land and have to try the tools listed in "Native Memory Leaks from Outside the JVM" (jemalloc, valgrind, Purify, etc.).